# Converting 32 bit image to 8 bit palette raster image using FME

Tags: raster, fme-form

I need to convert 32-bit TIFF image (input) to 8-bit palette TIFF image (output) by using FME.

How can I do this by using palette of output image?

[image: input 32 bit image information]

[image: output 8bit image information]

Answer (score 2):

In FME you would use a RasterPaletteGenerator transformer, like so:

[image]

What I will say is that I don't think GeoTIFF supports a 32-bit palette. i.e. even though I add an alpha band with the RasterBandAdder, and even though the RasterPaletteGenerator creates me a palette with RGBA values, the GeoTIFF output palette only has RGB values.

The log file tells me:

> 2020-02-20 10:04:22|   8.6|  0.0|WARN  |GEOTIFF writer: Unsupported
>   palette value interpretation 'RGBA32'. Converting to interpretation
>   'RGB24'. If this conversion is undesired, consider changing the
>   interpretation explicitly

So, you can get an 8-bit image with a palette easily enough, but even if your input is 32-bit RGBA, the palette will be 24-bit RGB.

Comment: I suppose this create palette using input image. I need to use the exist palette from earlier version.

Comment: Ah, then I think you need the RasterPaletteResolver transformer.